# How can I remove the comma in the url?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using this entry:

```
@misc{site1,
   howpublished = {\url{http://www.dylansimon.com/blog/carbon-fiber}}
}
```

So I have this:

> http://www.dylansimon.com/blog/carbon-fiber, .

How can I remove the comma at the ends of the url ?

Comment: Hi and welcome, this is defined with your bibliography style. You haven't given any useful information, please provide a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html) (<- follo the Link) so we can propose a proper solution.

Comment: If you use `biblatex` and the `url` field instead of `howpublished`, you should have no comma.

Comment: I'm using natbib. So if I put url instead of howpublished, I don't get the pdf file !

Comment: My bibliography style is: unsrtnat

Comment: Please follow the link in my first comment.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit of a puzzle to me how you might be generating the output you say you're getting. With the `unsrtnat` bibliography style, the `@misc` entry type has no required fields. If, as you seem to be indicating, the entry has a single field (the `howpublished` field), there should be *no comma* between the URL and the closing `.` (period). I can only guess that the entry has some additional fields you're not showing.

Here's what's produced if the entry has a normal complement of `field`s and the `unsrtnat` bibliography style is used. Note the comma between the URL string and the year.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{abcxyz.bib}
@misc{ds:2014,
    author   = "Dylan Simon",
    title    = "Carbon Fiber",
    year     = 2014,
    howpublished = "\url{http://www.dylansimon.com/blog/carbon-fiber/}",
    note     = "Last accessed on 2015/02/05",
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\begin{document}
\cite{ds:2014}
\bibliography{abcxyz}
\end{document}
```

---

If you cannot stand the comma after the URL, I suggest you (i) change the field from `howpublished` to `url` so that the URL is printed *after* the year (taking care to omit the `\url{...}` wrapper) and (ii) omit the `note` field. (If you don't omit the `note` field, its contents will be printed *after* the URL, with a `.` separating the two fields.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{abcxyz.bib}
@misc{ds:2014,
    author   = "Dylan Simon",
    title    = "Carbon Fiber",
    year     = 2014,
    url = "http://www.dylansimon.com/blog/carbon-fiber/",
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\begin{document}
\cite{ds:2014}
\bibliography{abcxyz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did what you say and it works for me. Thank you.